# Not able to find gherkin plugin for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gherkin

I am trying creating a cucumber selenium java project in intellij
but not able to install gherkin plugin.

[image]

As in Image there is no gherkin plugin in marketpalce

Comment: Plugin Error
    Problems found loading plugins:
    Plugin "Cucumber for Java" was not loaded: required plugin "gherkin" not installed.
    Disable Cucumber for Java
    Open plugin manager

Comment: What IDE version/edition do you use? Gherkin plugin should be bundled.

Comment: 2017.3.7.....community edition

Comment: I looked at the plugin version page: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9164-gherkin/versions. There doesn't seem to be a version compatible with 2017.3.7. That's probably why it doesn't show up in the search. Strange, not sure why. I take it you are not allowed to upgrade to the latest Intellij?

Comment: You may switch to newer IDE versions (2018-2020)

Comment: Okay..Thank Guys!